# Restrict access to a certain URL prefix

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I want to block access to all URLs in my server except URLs starting with `/myapp/path`, excluding `/myapp/path/nope`, which should be blocked as well.

I tried:

```
nginx.org/server-snippets: |
  location = /myapp/path/nope { return 404; }
  location ^~ /myapp/path {}
  location / { return 404; }
```

But got 404 messages on URLs starting with `/myapp/path` as well. To be frank, even after reading the documentation and trying all sorts of things it seems I haven't figured out how nginx determines what location to serve. What it wrong with my snippet? Thanks!

Comment: Omitting `^~` from the third line results in allowing all the URLs... I don't get it

Comment: You will also get a 404 response if the value of `root` is incorrectly set. Are there any entries in the error log, and where is the file `nginx.org/server-snippets` included into the rest of your configuration?

Comment: No errors, and this annotation is part of the ingress yaml. Apart from the `nginx.org/server-snippets` annotation the ingress works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I resolved this issue using a negative regex.
In my question I used the location and the regex incorrectly, as I never told nginx what to do with the path I wrote.

So in order to restrict access to anything that doesn't start with `/myapp/path` use:

```
location ~ ^/(?!myapp/path) { return 404; } # Or deny all;
```